# How to control what the buttons in push notifications do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, push-notification

I'm able to send push notifications to iOS devices. There is a "Close" button on the notification and a "View" button. When the user hits the "View" button the app opens up to the root view controller. Within the app there is a news section. Let's say the notification is to alert the user that there is a new news story for them to see. If they hit "View", the root view controller will show, instead of the news view controller. How would I go about opening the news view controller? Facebook uses this a lot. Would this be something to change on the server or within the app? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the launch options in your application delegate:

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

There you can obtain the payload dictionary of the push notification.

Comment: So what line would I put in the payload to specify this?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 8+ action button in notifications:

For **local notification**, `appDelegate` calls this method when a button on the notification (lock screen or banner) is pressed:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
   handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
         forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
            completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

For **push notification**, `appDelegate` calls this method when a button on the notification (lock screen or banner) is pressed:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
   handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
        forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
            completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```